# How to differentiate a path integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If we define the potential of a flow $\textbf{u}(x,y,z) = (u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z),w(x,y,z))$
$$\phi(\textbf{x}) = \int_O^{\textbf{x}}\textbf{u}\cdot \text{d} \textbf{x}$$

I want $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$

Consider

$$\phi((x + \delta x,y,z)) - \phi(\textbf{x}) =  \int_{(0,0,0)}^{(\delta x,0,0)}\textbf{u}\cdot \text{d} \textbf{x}  = \int^{\delta x}_0 u \text{d}x$$
so 
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = \lim_{\delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\int^{\delta x}_0 u \text{d}x}{\delta x}$$

This last part would be nice if I could take the $u$ out of the integral. How do I deal with this?

Could I suppose that an antiderivative of $u$ exists? Let this be $U$, then 
$$\frac{1}{\delta x}\int^{\delta x}_0 u \text{d}x = \frac{U(\delta x) - U(0)}{\delta x}$$
from which the result follows that 
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = u$$

Comment: This is it. (Though your integration limits are wrong.) And $\nabla \phi=\mathbb u$.

Comment: Why are my integration limits wrong? I can not see why

Comment: $x+\delta x$...

Comment: Oh my bad, yes. I just got confused for a second. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_{(x,y,z)}^{(x+h,y,z)} \mathbf{u}(x',y',z') \cdot d\mathbf{x}' = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{(x,y,z)}^{(x+h,y,z)} u(x',y',z') \, dx' $$
Now use the [mean value theorem for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals): if $u$ is continuous, there is $\theta=\theta(x,h)$ with $0<\theta<1$ so that
$$ \int_{(x,y,z)}^{(x+h,y,z)} u(x',y',z') \, dx' = u(x+\theta h,y,z)h. $$
Dividing by $h$ and taking $h \to 0$ gives the result.